# Joining strings in ibm CPLEX

Tags: string, cplex

I'm quite new with ibm cplex and I am developing a program in which I need to join, e.g., concatenate two string variables. The code I'm trying to implement is:

```
string sheet=...;
string rangename=sheet+"edges"
```

The problem is an error appears that says "operator not available for string + string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scripting within OPL](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/javascript-within-opl-cplex-alex-fleischer/)

```
string sheet="s";
string rangename;

execute
{
  rangename=sheet+"edges";
  writeln(rangename);
}
```

gives

```
sedges
```